# access a mysql db and displaying it in a gridview or table

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

I am trying to access a Mysql DB and display it in a Gridview in .Net
I can get it to connect to the DB, but it displays nothing and there is records in the DB, this is the code i am using.

```
Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
Dim ContactsCommand As New MySqlCommand
Dim ContactsAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim ContactsData As New DataTable
Dim SQL As String

Private Sub btnGrabData_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGrabData.Click

    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()
    SQL = "SELECT AffID FROM toutcome"

    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=merrywoodtest;UID=MerryWoodTest;PWD=H0r$hamTest;"

    Try

        MysqlConn.Open()

        ContactsCommand.Connection = MysqlConn
        ContactsCommand.CommandText = SQL

        ContactsAdapter.SelectCommand = ContactsCommand
        ContactsAdapter.Fill(ContactsData)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = ContactsData

    Catch myerror As MySqlException

        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database: " & myerror.Message)

    Finally

        MysqlConn.Close()

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the fill line, then press F10 once and check your variable: ContactsData and see if there's data, I would assume not. On another note, if your writing other queries make sure to use parameters, otherwise you would be acceptable for SQL injections.

Comment: Can you recommend a easier way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you will call **DataBind**() method of **DataGridView** after the data source is assinged.

You may also set the **Connection** property of the **ContactsCommand** object and the **SelectCommand** property of the  **ContactsAdapter** object.